# Unable to publish odometry for Unitree A1 Quadruped Robot

Tags: ros-melodic, lidar, gazebo-plugin, base-odometry, tf

I am working on Unitree A1 Quadruped Robot on ROS Melodic (Ubuntu 18.04). I have cloned the [unitree_guide](https://github.com/unitreerobotics/unitree_guide) repository.

When i run `roslaunch unitree_guide gazeboSim.launch`,  I cannot see `/odom` and `/cmd_vel` topics published. I need to publish those topics for slam. how can i do that?

**Update:**

1. I tried editing `gazebo.xacro` file in the `a1_description` folder by adding `odometryTopic`, `odometryFrame` ,`publishOdomTF` but I don't see any odom topic published.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Are you referri to Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) release instead of Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion I am using Ubuntu 18.04(Bionic). I tried editing gazebo.xacro file in the a1_description folder by adding <odometryTopic>, <odometryFrame> ,<publishOdomTF> but I don't see any odom topic published.